# Is there an R function for selecting image with best brightness histogram?

Tags: image, histogram, brightness, photography

I have hemispherical canopy images where for each tree/date, I took at least 3 (sometimes more) images with different exposure compensations (usually 0, +1/3 and -1/3) to account for variable light conditions. Some occasions I took more as the live view histogram in camera showed the image was still saturated at either end of histogram so required more under- or over-exposure. My question is now that I have ~10,000 images, but only want to analyse I image per tree/date sampling event, is there an automated way to select which of the 3+ images had the best exposure?
Or will I have to manually look at the histograms again...